# Unexpected results when using a std::priority_queue of struct pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, std, priority-queue, stdvector

I'm sure that the code is pretty self-explicative, so I go straight to the point. Please ask for more details if the code is unclear.

```
Foo.h
=====

#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo(){};
    Foo();
    Foo(const int b);
    bool operator<(const Foo&) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Foo&);

    int b;
};

Foo.cpp
=======

#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo()
{
}

Foo::Foo(const int b)
{
    this->b = b;
}

bool Foo::operator<(const Foo& other) const
{
    return b < other.b;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& f)
{
    os << '{' << f.b << '}';
    return os;
}

Bar.h
=====

#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include "Foo.h"

class Bar
{
    struct FooPp
    {
        Foo f;
        int a;

        FooPp(const Foo&);
        bool operator<(const FooPp&) const;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const FooPp& fpp)
        {
            os << '[' << fpp.a << "]," << fpp.f;
            return os;
        }
    };

    struct foopp_compare
    {
        bool operator()(const FooPp* pA, const FooPp* pB ) const 
        {
            return *pA < *pB;
        }
    };

public:
    virtual ~Bar(){};
    Bar(const std::vector<Foo>&);

    std::vector<FooPp> vf;
    std::priority_queue<FooPp*, std::vector<FooPp*>, foopp_compare> fq;
};

Bar.cpp
=======

#include "Bar.h"

Bar::FooPp::FooPp(const Foo& f)
{
    this->f = f;
    a = f.b;
}

bool Bar::FooPp::operator<(const FooPp& other) const
{
    return f < other.f;
}

Bar::Bar(const std::vector<Foo>& vf)
{
    for (std::vector<Foo>::const_iterator f = vf.begin();
            f != vf.end();
                ++f)
    {
        this->vf.push_back(*f);
        fq.push(&(this->vf.back()));
    }
}

main.cpp
========

#include <iostream>
#include "Bar.h"

int main()
{
    // Foo
    Foo f1(1);
    Foo f2(6);
    std::vector<Foo> vf;
    vf.push_back(f1);
    vf.push_back(f2);
    // Bar
    Bar b(vf);
    // print b.vf: [1]{1}, [6],{6};
    std::cout << b.vf[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << b.vf[1] << '\n';
    // print the top of the prio_q: [6],{6};
    std::cout << *(b.fq.top()) << '\n';
    // change "a" in b.vf[1] -> [-12],{6}
    b.vf[1].a = -12;
    // print b.vf[1]: [-12],{6};
    std::cout << b.vf[1] << '\n';
    // print the top of the prio_q: [-12],{6};
    std::cout << *(b.fq.top()) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I get instead:

```
./example 
[1],{1}            // OK
[6],{6}            // OK
[1],{135704652}    // ??
[-12],{6}          // OK
[1],{135704652}    // ??
```

It seems that the `std::vector<FooPp>` is initialized correctly, but I do not understand what's happening with the `std::priority_queue`, which should have been initialized with pointers to elements of the `std::vector<FooPp>`. What's wrong?

By the way.. this is the makefile for those of you that are on Unix machines

```
Makefile
========

CXX      := g++
LD       := g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -g -O0 --std=c++0x -I.

SRC := $(shell ls *.cpp)
OBJ := ${SRC:%.cpp=%.o}

.PHONY: clean

example: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ) *~ example
```

Comment: You know that a `std::vector` may invalidate all references/pointers and iterators to its elements when you use `push_back`?

Comment: Ok, so what do you suggest here? Should I use a double loop (the first one to `push_back` `Foo` objects into `vf` and the second one to `push` `&vf[i]` into the prio_q)?

Comment: @MatteoM. You can just initialize your member vector from the parameter directly in the initializer list, then use the loop for pushing pointers into your priority queue.

Comment: @MatteoM. I'm quite uncomfortable with those two data members being public. The constructor establishes some relation between the two, but as they're public, there's no guarantee the user of the class won't break that relation (e.g. by using a `push_back`).

Comment: @DyP Of course this is just test code. The data members wouldn't be public in production code...

Comment: (Also, since `std::priority_queue<FooPp*, ..>` has reference semantics, you should define appropriate copy/move ctors and assignment opererators; or delete them.)

Comment: This is quite a lot of code: a 10-line [testcase](http://sscce.org) might have been better. That said, well done for being thorough and exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the underlying vector `vf` with each push, and invalidating all iterators (and addresses taken from them therein) in the process.

The quickest way I see to fix this is modifying the constructor for `Bar`:

```
Bar::Bar(const std::vector<Foo>& vf)
    : vf(vf.begin(), vf.end())
{
    for (std::vector<FooPp>::iterator f = this->vf.begin();
         f != this->vf.end();
         ++f)
    {
        fq.push(&(*f));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[1],{1}
[6],{6}
[6],{6}
[-12],{6}
[-12],{6}
```

There are a *host* of other things I would do with this code (using initializer lists, etc.), but that is about the smallest code change I can think of that will deliver you something that works.

Comment: And never touch it again ;)

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok. This is quite similar to what I meant above with "double loop". The first one initialize vf and the second one the prio_q. I like your `vf(vf.begin(), vf.end())` to save my first loop though. Thank you all guys

Comment: The copy and move constructors would be completely broken as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is here

```
Bar::Bar(const std::vector<Foo>& vf)
{
    for (std::vector<Foo>::const_iterator f = vf.begin();
            f != vf.end();
                ++f)
    {
        this->vf.push_back(*f);
        fq.push(&(this->vf.back()));
    }
}
```

When you add new elements to the vector it can reallocate the used memory. So this value &(this->vf.back()) becomes invalid.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Should I use a double loop here? I mean the first one to `vf.push_back` all the `Foo`s and another one to `push(&vf[i])`?

Comment: @ Matteo M I think it will be better if you at first will form the vector and only after that will form the queue provided that the vector will not be changed any more..

Comment: @Matteo: I think we call that "two loops", not one "double loop" =)